# C++ How to ignore the difference between upper and lower when checking Palindrome?

Tags: c++, palindrome

```
bool isPalindrome(const char *s1)
{

  const char *start, *end;

  start = s1;
  end = s1 + strlen(s1) - 1;


  while (start < end)
      if(*start++ != *end--)
        return false;
  return true; 
}
```

I write the code about checking Palindrome, but ignore the requirement of ignoring difference between upper and lower.
I have no idea about that.
Can you help me?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a function called "tolower" which will take an upper case letter and convert it to a lowercase letter. It will return the value unchanged if it was already lowercase or it was not a letter. Your code as written is very close to being entirely correct and only needs a slight change.

```
if(*start++ != *end--)
```

will become

```
if(tolower(*start++) != tolower(*end--))
```

Comment: Note that `tolower` is locale dependant and by default only works for ASCII letters unless you specify a different locale